# The session comes with information, but it doesn't show up without refreshing the page

Tags: php, session, refresh

Check the information on the login.php page and direct it to the header.php. The information comes in the session but does not show information without refresh the page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you use php you have to reload, use js if you want it to show without refreshing

Comment: You can use AJAX, if you want to do something without refreshing page